# Emulator on Android SDK failed to start on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova

I am working with Ionic Cordova project and trying to run emulator. I am using trial version of windows 10 pro, till now didn't put license, it is trial only. though Android studio, Java sdk, and Android-SDK installed correctly but when trying to start emulator (for a correctly created virtual image) it is failing to start. It is visible for 1 seconds after that it is never visible. In-fact event viewer also not showing any error log. is it due to trial version of win 10 pro? I have no clue why it is happening?

I have tried by both installing hyper-v and once unstalling hyper-v, but none worked. I am not sure if hyper-v feature should be on or off. What is correct way?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the emulators and SDK exactly? What Android SDK version is the emulator based on? Are you really using Visual Studio and the Tools for Apache Cordova? What VS version, cordova and cordova-android versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you see emulator icon, but don't see window, just recreate emulator. This is because of bugs with emulator position (when emulator window is off-screen).

Anyway, try recreating virtual device